# Estimote: Change update interval to 5 Hz

Tags: swift, estimote

I'm using the Estimote SDK (3.6.0) for the communication with my beacons. Now I have read somewhere, that it is possible to get the advertisement package of the beacons with 5 Hz. Is this only possible with Estimote beacons or does this work with beacons of other vendors too? 
Where can I change this update interval in the source code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Each beacon vendor usually provides some means to adjust their beacons' settings. Most often, that's in form of an app that you can download from the App Store or Google Play Store. In this particular case (Estimote), that'll be an app is simply called "Estimote." For more details, you should consult the vendor's documentation or inquire with their support team (:

One final thought: with Estimote Beacons, you operate on advertising **interval** of the beacon (i.e., the time between packets being broadcast) instead of **frequency**. Since one is just an inverse of the other, 5 Hz frequency (= 5 times a second) is equivalent to a 200 ms interval.